# change the color and the font of NStextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am trying to change the color and the font size of NSTextView but it doesn't seem to work.This is my code.I have checked other posts but they dont seem to be working.This is my code.

```
 var area:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, textView.textStorage!.length)
 self.textView.setTextColor(NSColor.grayColor(), range: area)
 self.textView.textStorage?.font = NSFont(name: "Calibri", size: 16)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use attributed strings:

```
let textView = NSTextView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.redColor(),
                  NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.blackColor()]
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "my string", attributes: attributes)
let area = NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)
if let font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica Neue Light", size: 16) {
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: area)
    textView.textStorage?.appendAttributedString(attrStr)
}
```

[image: Playground]